# how to fix position of link in over mouse hover

Tags: html, css

there is a problom when over mouse the list the deep list show in top of the page , please help me guys

here is the html code

```
<div  id="mymenu" runat="server" >
      <ul class="mainmenu">
      <li><a>WorkFlow</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="# >Employee Apprisail Report</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Attendance Amendment Status Report</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Employee Requisition Report</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Employee Clearance Report</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Employee Hiring Status Report</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Housing Loan Status Report</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Leave Request Annulal Leave Amendments</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Leave Request Annulal Leave Cancellation</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Mobile Allowance Status Report</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Overtime Status Report</a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
       <li><a>HR</a>
       <ul class="submenu">
       <li><a href="#">Iqama Report</a></li>
       <li><a href="#>Project Time Attendance System</a></li>
       <li><a href="#”>Vacation Balance Report</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Electronic Human Resource Mangment System</a></li>
       </ul>
       </li>
        <li><a>Payroll</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">Manual Attendance System/User Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Manual Attendance System Approve/Reject</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Check Print/Report</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Head Of Departmens Attendance Amendment</a></li>
        <li><a href=”#">Overtime Payroll Application</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Salary Increment Status Report</a></li>
        <li><a href="#”>Payroll Reconciliation Report</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

here is my css (problome)

```css
ul.mainmenu:
{
 list-style:none;
}

ul.mainmenu li
 {
    display: inline-block;
}

ul.mainmenu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #ff005a;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0.25em;
}

ul.mainmenu li a:hover {
    background: #ff00ff;
}

ul.mainmenu li ul.submenu {
    list-style: none;
    display: none;
}

ul.mainmenu li:hover > ul.submenu {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Can you make us a jsfiddle please?

Answer (score 0):

Any element positioned with `position: absolute` is positioned relative to the first of its parent elements with its `position` property set to anything other than `static` (the default), or, in the case of no elements having a non-`static` position it'll be positioned relative to the `body` element.

To fix that simply assign `position: relative` to a parent element, for example the `li`:

```
ul.mainmenu li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And simply use `top` and `left` to appropriately position the 'drop-down' menu.